# I want to encrypt folder

Tags: 20.04

I just switched to linux (5 hours ago)
I am still trying to encrypt my most important folders.

There seems to be no easy solution for that.

What would you suggest to encrypt few folders?

Comment: One easy way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584461/gpg-encryption-and-decryption-of-a-folder-using-command-line

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs is easy to use. You don't need a separate filesystem for it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you do not want to create a separate partition (volume) for your encrypted files, then you should use ***eCryptfs***.

> eCryptfs stores cryptographic metadata in the header of each file
> written, so that encrypted files can be copied between hosts; the file
> will be decryptable with the proper key, and there is no need to keep
> track of any additional information aside from what is already in the
> encrypted file itself.

Installation of eCryptfs:

```
$ sudo apt install ecryptfs-utils
```

Setup is easy. First, create your “private” directory that will contain the encrypted files and sub-directories. For example:

```
$ mkdir ~/Documents/private
```

When this directory is not “mounted”, you can look at the contents of the files in it, but you will see nothing meaningful, since everything will be encrypted. To use (read & write) to the unencrypted version of it, you should “mount” this directory. You can mount this directory over to itself like this:

```
$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs ~/Documents/private ~/Documents/private
```

Since this is the first time you try to mount this directory with eCryptfs, you will answer a few questions like this:

- First, enter a passphrase that you **will never forget**.
- Cipher: aes (default)
- Key bytes: 32
- Plaintext passthrough: n (default)
- Filename encryption: n (default)

Now, the important warning:

```
WARNING: Based on the contents of [/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt],
it looks like you have never mounted with this key 
before. This could mean that you have typed your 
passphrase wrong.

Would you like to proceed with the mount (yes/no)? :
```

Since this is the first time you mount this directory, you will answer `yes` so that a new file called `~root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt` will be created, which will contain a “signature” of the passphrase.

```
Would you like to append sig [xxxxxxxxxxxx] to
[/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt] 
in order to avoid this warning in the future (yes/no)? :
```

Answer also `yes` to this question so the file `~root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt` will be populated.

Later, when we re-mount this directory we should not get this warning, **unless we enter the wrong passphrase**.

Create a file in the private directory. For example:

```
$ ls -al > ~/Documents/private/1.txt
```

Note the length of the file:

```
$ wc -c ~/Documents/private/1.txt
4935 ...
```

Unmount the directory:

```
$ sudo umount ~/Documents/private
```

Look at the encrypted version of the file in the unmounted `~/Documents/private` directory:

```
$ less  ~/Documents/private/1.txt
```

It seems like a binary file, because its contents are encrypted.

Look at the length of the file:

```
$ wc -c ~/Documents/private/1.txt
16384 ...
```

It is a few kilobytes larger than the unencrypted file, since it contains some metadata. This is the whole overhead of eCryptfs on your file system: Each file will be about 8 to 16KB larger that what it would be if it were not encrypted.

Re-mount the directory using the command:

```
$ sudo mount -t ecryptfs ~/Documents/private ~/Documents/private \
-o ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,\
ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=no,\
ecryptfs_sig=$(sudo cat ~root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt)
```

Enter correct passphrase. If you enter the wrong passphrase, you will get the message:

```
WARNING: Based on the contents of [/root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt],
it looks like you have never mounted with this key 
before. This could mean that you have typed your 
passphrase wrong.

Would you like to proceed with the mount (yes/no)? :
```

In such a case, answer `no` to this and re-try with the correct passphrase.

Check the contents once more.

```
$ less ~/Documents/private/1.txt
$ wc -c ~/Documents/private/1.txt
4935 ...
```

For more information, look at [`man ecryptfs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man7/ecryptfs.7.html).

Comment: I had to remove `ecryptfs_sig=$(sudo cat ~root/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt)` from the re-mount command to make it work

Comment: What's your recommendation if I want to create a separate partition and encrypt?@FedKad

Comment: Obviously LUKS. @JuneWang

Comment: Like this https://linuxconfig.org/partition-encryption ? If you set automount at reboot and connects through SSH, will it ask for passphrase? It also didn't mention how to enter passphrase when manual mount tho. @FedKad

Comment: This post mentions `~root/…` and `/root/…`, I used only `/root/…` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

not something I have tried myself but I have found the following for you

https://itsfoss.com/password-protect-folder-linux/

this does cover Ubuntu so I hope will help you.

There is the alternative of whole disk encryption which is transparent to you as the user but would stop the disk being read externally without the code.

It is unclear why you need folder locking in the  first place.
File permissions in Linux/Ubuntu allow you to lock it to the specific user (and administrators = superusers = sudo) with no access to others.
If multi users on your systems a simple right click and permission to no access for folders may suffice to secure private data, assuming other users do NOT have admin access.

And welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: What's unclear? File permissions don't prevent superusers and if someone manages hack their way to superuser, you'd still like them to not be able to view sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

I have LUKS1 on LVM, which encrypts whole disc including `/boot`, see
https://cryptsetup-team.pages.debian.net/cryptsetup/encrypted-boot.html