# Protect my webapp

Tags: encryption, webapps

Good day folks,
I'm developing a webapp that will be distributed on a minipc that will be installed at my clients' workplace.

I would like to protect my source code from being accessed in case my customer takes out the hard drive and connects it to another PC as an external drive.

I need to protect only /var/www/ or at least some key files in it

I've searched the forum but haven't found anything that works.

Thanks to whoever will answer me

Comment: Encryption might be about the only thing you can do to protect that code.  You haven't mentioned what OS you are using or the version number.  That being said, you can look into something like ecryptfs https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281476/i-want-to-encrypt-folder

Answer (score 1):

You really can't.

What you're asking for is DRM. It didn't work on DVDs, and it won't work in your scenario.

You should rely on legal means (e.g. licenses and license enforcement) for protecting your intellectual property. Technical means doesn't really work.

If that's unfeasible, then don't distribute it; offer your application as a service in the cloud.